# How to format regex?

Tags: regex

I have this:
https://regexr.com/3jo8c

what i want is to have valid only like this:

from 10,00-  to 10,99
    from 100,00 - to 100,99
     from 1000,00 - to 1000,99

so to have always x,**xx**

and so on.
 Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `x` by `[0-9]` in your question and you almost have the answer:

```
[0-9]+,[0-9]{2}
```

The `+` will ensure that you have any number (except zero) of digits before the comma. The `{2}` ensures that you have two digits after.